# String replacement on a file based on multiple files as reference

Tags: python, shell, unix, awk, fasta

[Looking for a solution preferably using UNIX tools, but Python would work as well]

I have three files, where the first will contain strings called 'headers' (starting with >) followed by a line with characters, the second will contain IDs and names, and the third will contain many columns, including the header from the first file ($1), an ID on the second file ($3) and some relevant attributes I want to add to the string on the first file, as per the following example:

File1) Data (a fasta file with sequence data)

```
>[Header1]
ATCGATCGATCG
>[Header2]
CGGTAAGCTAGCTAG
>[Header3]
TCTGTACTGCATGCA
...
```

File2) IDs and names

```
>[ID1] [Name1]
>[ID2] [Name2]
>[ID3] [Name3]
```

File3) Crossreference table - file with 13 fields (fields 6-11 don't matter)

```
[Header],"[Size];",[ID],[PRCNT],[AL],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[EVAL],[SCORE]
```

I need to replace the 'header' string on the first file with a new string, made up of a name (2nd file) crossreferenced using the 3rd file and multiple fields of the 3rd file.

What I need is to look at file3 (the Crossreference table), look at the first field (Header), then store the other values. Using the value of the third field (Number), look up on file2 (IDs and names) the appropriate Name and store it, and then simply rewrite file1, changing the stored Header with a new string, made up of all relevant fields on the Crossreference table, plus the Name in the File2
The way I'm currently doing this is as follows:

```
counter=1
while read Header Size ID PRCNT AL F6 F7 F8 F9 F10 F11 EVAL SCORE; do
    name=`grep ^">$ID" File2`
    newheader=">$counter|PRCNT_$PRCNT|AL_$AL|eval_$EVAL|score_$SCORE|Size_${Size%;}|$name"
    echo -en "\r"; echo -en "Renaming headers ($counter/$totalnumber)   "
    sed -i "s#^>$Header#$newheader#" File1
    ((counter+=1))
done < File3
```

That way, I replace `[Header]` with `{unique_number}|PRCNT_{field4_file3}|AL_{field5_file3}|eval_{field12_file3}|score_{field13_file3}|Size_{field2_file3-removing_';'}|{full_line_file2}`

It works precisely as I need it to work, except it takes a long time to run (as I have thousands of 'headers'), and I'm sure there must be a simpler (and faster) way to do it, except I don't know which way that would be...

What I need is a simple way to handle all three files, the one containing my Data with the headers, the one with the proper names and the one that crossreferences both (and has all attributes of them), and then reprinting the data file with fixed 
headers (showing the proper names and all relevant attributes).

I'd prefer a solution using UNIX tools (sed, awk, grep, etc.), but python would also work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding sample input/output as requested

File1)

```
>This_is_my_header_number_1
TCGTACGTCACTAATCGAG
>And_here_is_number_2
TCAGCAGTCATCATACTGCGTA
```

File2)

```
>19846 Proper name foo bar faa 124;k__name
>949 A name that does not appear on either other file
>24728 Name foo nonrelated la;k__laa
```

File3) [All lines here will match a header in File1 and a line in File2)

```
This_is_my_header_number_1  103;    19846   0.83    502 foo faa bar 849 97510   1111    5e-10   1005
And_here_is_number_2    44; 24728   0.98    301 wol olo fii 235 889 9123    2e-20   3045
```

OUTPUT:

```
1|PRCNT_0.83|AL_502|eval_5e-10|score_1005|Size_103|>19846 Proper name foo bar faa 124;k__name
TCGTACGTCACTAATCGAG
2|PRCNT_0.98|AL_301|eval_2e-20|score_3045|Size_44|>24728 Name foo nonrelated la;k__laa
TCAGCAGTCATCATACTGCGTA
```

Notice that the headers have been replaced, but the line under the headers (the sequences of A, T, C and Gs) remain unchanged. Lines in file2 that are not matched by any ID on File3 are ignored. All headers on file1 will appear on File3, even if not all 'IDs' on file2 do.

Comment: Please post sample expected output too in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Just added it as requested, thank you.

Comment: Request to please update sample of inputs/outputs with small samples(anyways logic will be same for small or longer) so that we could better understand it.

Comment: File3 has ',' as a separator or space as a separator?

Answer (score 0):

Well...
Having a file named `1` with the content:

```
>This_is_my_header_number_1
TCGTACGTCACTAATCGAG
>And_here_is_number_2
TCAGCAGTCATCATACTGCGTA
```

and a file named `2` with the content:

```
>19846 Proper name foo bar faa 124;k__name
>949 A name that does not appear on either other file
>24728 Name foo nonrelated la;k__laa
```

and a file named `3` with the content:

```
This_is_my_header_number_1  103;    19846   0.83    502 foo faa bar 849 97510   1111    5e-10   1005
And_here_is_number_2    44; 24728   0.98    301 wol olo fii 235 889 9123    2e-20   3045
```

running the following command:

```
sed "$(
        sed 's/^>//' 2 | sort \
        | join -13 -21 <(sort -k3 3) - \
        | sed \
's#\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)_\([0-9]*\) \([^ ]*\); \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \(.*\)#'\
'\2_\3 \3|PRCNT_\5|AL_\6|eval_\7|score_\8|Size_\4|>\1 \9#;'\
's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/s@>\1@\2@;/'
)" <1
```

produces the following output:

```
1|PRCNT_0.83|AL_502|eval_5e-10|score_1005|Size_103|>19846 Proper name foo bar faa 124;k__name
TCGTACGTCACTAATCGAG
2|PRCNT_0.98|AL_301|eval_2e-20|score_3045|Size_44|>24728 Name foo nonrelated la;k__laa]
TCAGCAGTCATCATACTGCGTA
```

What happens here?

- I take the file 2 and remove the leading `>` sign.
- Then I take the file 3
- Then I sort file 2 (on first column) and sort file 3 on column 3 (ID)
- Then I join file 3 on 3rd column (ID) with first column in file 2
  (ID)
- Then I transform the fields into the string `<header> <the line that should be substituded for header, that looks as fancy as you specified>`
- Then I generate sed substitute command that look like `s@<header>@<the line that should be substituded for header>@;` for each header I need to substitute.
- The I run sed with the generated argument on file `1` substituting headers.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='>' '
   NR==FNR{
     a[$1]=$2
     next
   }
   !n{
     b[substr($1,2)]=substr($0,index($0," ")+1)
     next
   }
   n==1{
     print FNR,"PRCNT_"$4,"AL_"$5,"eval_"$12,"score_"$13,"Size_"$2,">"$3" "b[$3]
     print a[$1] 
   }' file1 RS='\n' file2 n=1  OFS='|' file3
```

The 3 block statements associated to parsing both 3 files.

The first 2 block fill respectively the array `a` and `b` with the content of the `file1` and `file2`.

The last block is printed the expected line by looking up in to the arrays.

Note that the switch between files is done together with bothe `NR==FNR` to match the first file and the variable `n` which is unset for `file2` and set to `1` for `file3`.